# Releasing app for Android v4.4.3+ only?

Tags: android

We have an Android project. Using the minSdkVersion set to API level 19 it's possible to release an app requiring Android 4.4 KitKat.

However, how would one release an app for at least 4.4.**3** only? (We have a game which stands and falls with having Canvas hardware acceleration in web view, which was introduced in 4.4.3 only.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can not restrict APK distribution to minor versions in the Google Play Store. The only thing you can do is to require API level 19 using `minSdkVersion` and then do a runtime check against `android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE` in your app, refusing to run if it is below 4.4.3.

Comment: (Thanks, and what is the appropriate action on StackOverflow if the answer is correct but there is no solution... should I accept as answer or leave open?)

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125855/should-i-answer-my-own-question-with-it-cant-be-done you should accept it I think.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to target just Android 5, by using the [newly added](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) API level 21. While this doesn't answer how to target 4.4.3+ specifically, it will guarantee that the mentioned Canvas hardware acceleration is available on the target device.